# Get latest value of an Observable and a Behaviour Subject

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a observable and a behaviour subject. I want to get their latest values, check if they are both true and assign the result to an observable.

1. Observable will select a boolean from the NgRx Store:

   ```
   this.i18nStateService.defaultMarketChangeTriggered()
   ```
2. BehaviourSubject is also a boolean

   ```
   this.cookieService.isCookieLayerConfirmed$
   ```

This is my approach.

```
   this.result$ = this.i18nStateService.defaultMarketChangeTriggered()
              .pipe(
                map(defaultMarketChangedTriggered => defaultMarketChangedTriggered  && !this.cookieService.isCookieLayerConfirmed$)
              );
```

Comment: `isCookieLayerConfirmed$` is an observable so using this as variable is wrong. Use `combineLatest` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a combination approach. Try using `combineLatest`.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

this.result$ = combineLatest(this.i18nStateService.defaultMarketChangeTriggered(),
                             this.cookieService.isCookieLayerConfirmed$).pipe(

            // pluck the combination of those two observables individually to these variables
       map(([defaultMarketChangeTriggered, isCookieLayerConfirmed]) => defaultMarketChangeTriggered && isCookieLayerConfirmed), 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many operators to combine or merge observables results, I think the Zip operator should be what you are looking for.
it merges two or more observable results two one stream.

```
import {zip} from "rxjs/observable/zip";

zip(this.i18nStateService.defaultMarketChangeTriggered(), this.cookieService.isCookieLayerConfirmed$).subscribe(t=>{});
```